# How can I call message without triggering members? (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like to be able to name message without the member being triggered as well, but whenever I want to specify only the message, member is triggered instead of message, can someone help me?

Here is the code:

```
@bot.hybrid_command(description='Test Command')
async def test(ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member=None, message=None):
    
    if message and member:
        return await ctx.reply(f"Test message and member are: {message} und {member.mention}", mention_author=False)
    elif message is None and member is not None:
        return await ctx.reply(f"Test member is: {member.mention}", mention_author=False)
    elif member is None and message is not None:
        return await ctx.reply(f"Test member is: {message}", mention_author=False)
    else:
        return await ctx.reply(f"Test failed", mention_author=False)
```

Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound: Member "Hello" not found.
```

I hope someone can help me. :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got u or not but if u want to avoid this error u can use a try to convert the member object

```
@bot.hybrid_command(description='Test Command')
async def test(ctx: commands.Context, member=None,message=None):
    try:
        converter = commands.MemberConverter()
        member = await converter.convert(ctx=ctx, argument=member)
        if message and member:
            return await ctx.reply(f"Test message and member are: {message} und {member.mention}", mention_author=False)
        elif message is None and member is not None:
            return await ctx.reply(f"Test member is: {member.mention}", mention_author=False)
        elif member is None and message is not None:
            return await ctx.reply(f"Test member is: {message}", mention_author=False)
    except:
        return await ctx.reply(f"Test failed", mention_author=False)
```